# JQuery - Cycle multiple images with url

Tags: php, jquery, cycle

I am rendering with php some amount of images, but also i render the `a href=""` - the images area changing when they are fading, but the url are the same.

How can I change the url and the image together?

JQuery Cycle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jquery Cycle plugin can cycle any any elment. So the easy way to do this is to just wrap each image with a hyperlink:

http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/MV9S5/

```
<div id="slideshow">
  <a href="/page/a"><img src="img1.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="/page/b"><img src="img2.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="/page/c"><img src="img3.jpg" /></a>
</div>

$('#slideshow').cycle();
```

Additionally you can use your slide attributes if perhaps you have a title you want updated that is outside of the sliders.  You'd use the after event.  The following code updates the `h1`'s hyperlink after each slide changes.  It sets the text to be the title of the img on the slide.  Because my images are wrapped in a hyperlink, I need this line `var $cur = $('img', currSlideElement)`  to get to the img element of the slide.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/dsK9S/2/

```
<h1 id="title"><a href="#"></a></h1>
<div id="slideshow">
  <a href="/page/a"><img src="img1.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="/page/b"><img src="img2.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="/page/c"><img src="img3.jpg" /></a>
</div>
$('#slideshow').cycle({
    after:function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options, forwardFlag) {
        var $cur = $('img',currSlideElement);
        $('#title a').text($cur.attr('title'));
       $('#title a').attr('href',$cur.attr('src')).text();
    }
});
​
```

Comment: so i tried your first example, but when i make the "fade" effect, it doesn't change the url when fades

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery solution:**

```
$(yourImage).attr('src', 'newImageUrl');
```

If you are trying to implement a slider. Try [nivo](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/).

Comment: Oh the urls are same, so append `'?' + random number` at the end of url. Random number like `new Date().getTime()`.

Comment: the urls are different for each image